# Salesforce SOQL access the managed package object

Tags: package, managed, soql

In Account object, I have a custom field named "Company" which in a managed package (Namespace Prefix: act).
How can I get the value from this custom field by SOQL? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it;

```
SELECT act__Company__c FROM Account
```

Generically:

```
[tablePrefix].[NameSpace]__[Field]
```

[From this page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm) in the Salesforce documentation.